# MigraDoc PDFSharp - alignment of text frames

Tags: pdfsharp, migradoc

Section
 TextFrame
  Table
   Row 1 - N, Dynamically generated using a datatable.
 TextFrame
  Table
   Row 1 - N, Dynamically generated using a datatable.

The problem is when i create this document, the two TextFrame overlap each other, and i have to add paragraphs between those two to make them not overlap. The problem is, with more rows, i just can be sure how many add paragraphs are needed.

I am pretty sure there must be a right way to do it and not this:

```
for (int x = 0; x < tb.Rows.Count / 2; x++)
 section.AddParagraph();
```

Comment: I don't know how and why you add the TextFrames. You can add two tables to a section without TextFrames. Tables won't overlap then. What is the purpose of your TextFrames?

Comment: To indent the tables from the page margin. I am new at this so i figured that adding text frame was the best approach, to set a margin to the Text Frame, and then add the table in there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have to use TextFrames to indent tables. TextFrames won't break to the next page, so this "solution" will work for small tables only.

You can indent tables using the table.Rows.LeftIndent property (one would expect this to be a property of class Table, but it works).
See also:
http://forum.pdfsharp.net/viewtopic.php?p=4648#p4648

Comment: Thanks. I tried this and it works like a charm. I am sure getting more experienced at using MigraDoc and PDF Sharp now :).